# Java JPA: conditional predicates, how to leave out one depending on boolean

Tags: java, jpa

I have a few booleans, based on these boolean I need to include a `Predicate` in the `CriteriaQuery`. However, the approach in the given example 1 does not work, as a second call on the function `where()` will override any previous attributes. This means that only the last `Predicate` will be executed.

Normally you would stack the `Predicates` as seen in example 2.

However, due to the conditions given by the booleans this is not possible. I am trying to prevent a situation as seen in example 3. Any suggestions?

**Example 1**

```
function(boolean a, boolean b, boolean c) {
    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Product> query = cb.createQuery(Product.class);
    Root product = query.from(Product.class);

    query.select(product);

    if(a) {
        query.where(cb.equal(...));
    }
    if(b) {
        query.where(cb.equal(...));
    }
    if(c) {
        query.where(cb.equal(...));
    }

    return em.createQuery(query).getResultList();
}
```

**Example 2**

```
query.where(cb.equal(...), cb.equal(...), cb.equal(...));
```

**Example 3**

```
if(a && b && c) { query.where(cb.equal(...), cb.equal(...), cb.equal(...)); }
if(a && b && !c) { query.where(cb.equal(...), cb.equal(...)); }
if(a && !b && c) { query.where(cb.equal(...), cb.equal(...)); }
if(a && !b && !c) { query.where(cb.equal(...)); }
(...)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could collect them in a list and then set the where clause at the end, e.g. :

```
private final List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>(3);
...
if(a) {
    predicates.add(cb.equal(...));
}
if(b) {
    predicates.add(cb.equal(...));
}
if(c) {
    predicates.add(cb.equal(...));
}
...
query.where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]));
...
```

Comment: Oh ok, so an array is in fact the same as that I would post the multiple objects in the function? Did not know that... I had been reading the documentation but could not find anything about allowed lists, but this will give the same result.

Comment: Yep! Anywhere that you have a [Vararg](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html) "the final argument may be passed as an array or as a sequence of arguments" :)